# iOS Universal Development – Use of Tilde Sign (~) in Xib File and Image Name for differentiation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

While developing `universal apps`, we have to write a `conditional code` for each `device` – the `iPad` as well as the `iPhone`. In this scenario, the proper use of `tilde` can be extremely beneficial.

For example, if you want to push new view controller, then you’d have to write lot of lines (almost 10) of code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
  MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@”MasterViewController_iphone” bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:masterViewController animated:YES];
 [masterViewController release];
}
else
{
  MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@”MasterViewController_ipad” bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:masterViewController animated:YES];
  [masterViewController release];
}
```

**How can we differentiate images for iphone and ipad?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**For differentiating XIB file for iPhone and iPad** :

The magical `~` will help you. You can use it, to differentiate between iPhone and iPad assets / `xib` files.

Your file should end with `~iphone.xib`  or `~ipad.xib`.

**Note:** It's **case sensitive** don't use `iPad` or `iPhone`.

Check that each `xib` file has all outlets connected and has the correct fileowner set. If some are missing, iOS could decide not to use them and use the iPhone files instead.

**For differentiating Images for iphone and ipad**

Platform-specific modifiers—Use the modifiers ~iphone or ~ipad to specify images targeting a specific size of device.

Official document [InfoPlistKeyReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28)

Comment: Thanks for this thing... It's wonderful.. Do you have any official links of it ???

Comment: Itworks like charm .check [Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html) link where tilde has been used for differntiating between devices (iphone or ipad)

Comment: @Prince I tried by adding ~ipad with my xib name. Still small view only appears 1x or 2x in down right corner. Do I need to do anything more?

Comment: if small view appears i assume your app doesnot support ipad platform ie its not unversal app. Create new unversal app and add all viewcontroller class and xib in it.

Comment: Can I use this `~` to differentiate between landscape and portrait? If I am not wrong, I have seen like that before but I am not sure.

Comment: @MinSoe am not sure about orientation but can check you by yourself and let me know the result here?

Comment: @Prince I've already tried. Not working for orientation changes just with `~`.

Comment: was this introduced in a specific platform or do all versions of iOS support this? I don't think the document specifies that it was introduced in a specific version but wanted to make sure