# iPad views are not covering full screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I converted my xib developed into iPad specific xib by adding iPad.XIB and replacing IBCocoaTouchFramework with IBIPadFramework in source code editor mode. Still my views are not  covering full screen, lot of empty spaces are around the views and those views resolution also not good, Do I need to do anything extra other than that what I have mentioned above..

Edit:

I have created new project for iPad, its working fine, if I add new xib for iPad in my old project(iPhone) it is not working, Is there anything related to project we need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set autosizing in Size inspector?

Comment: Yes Auto Resize subviews should also be checked but I am taking about Size Inspector (Alt+Command+5) where you set size and origin of views.

Comment: I did, still the same problem. Is it possible like this, or Do I need to create new iPad xib only, Have you ever tried like this?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742930/ios-development-use-of-tilde-sign-in-file-name/13742931#13742931 for universal app

Comment: @Prince I tried by adding ~ipad with my xib name. Still small view only appears 1x or 2x in down right corner. Do I need to do anything more?

Comment: if small view appears i assume your app doesnot support ipad platform ie its not unversal app. Create new unversal app and add all viewcontroller class and xib in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if small view appears i assume your app doesnot support ipad platform ie its not unversal app. Create new unversal app and add all viewcontroller class and xib in it. – Prince

Answer (score 1):

You should check the device first using bellow code and now you create two xib with same class one xib for ipad and second for iphone and load with device wise..

```
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
     {
         //iphone
     }
     else
     {
         //ipad
     }
```

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    {



        masterViewController = [[cntrMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrMasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
        // loadingView =[LoadingView loadingViewInView:masterViewController.view:@"Please Wait.."];
        //masterViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;




        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

        } 
    else 
    {
        cntrMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[cntrMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrMasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];


        UIViewController *viewController1 = [[cntrMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"cntrMasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

          [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
          self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.window addSubview:self.viewController1.view];

}
```

Comment: So, we can't convert an iPhone xib into iPad one?. Because each xib is having many connection, I have to make all again.

Comment: i am not actually sure that it is possible to iphone xib to convert in ipad xib but i am do like this above method

Answer (score 1):

you have to set your view's subviews frame again to make them look fit in iPad screen. Do it in xib of iPad or programmaticaly, use nitin's method to load view based on what device you are working on

Answer (score 0):

Just check that the `xib` name you are putting is correct

```
yourViewController = [[yourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourIpadNibName" bundle:nil];
```

Just focus on `yourIpadNibName`