# How to have same storyboard name for iPhone & iPad in multiStoryBoard Universal App?

Tags: ios, nsstring, storyboard, ios-universal-app, tilde

I am creating a multiple storyboard app. On basis of requirement, I am using different story board at different instances. for supporting it all devices, I have to write my code like this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"blah_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
else
{         
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"blah_iPad" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I've tried using tilde (~) also, naming the storyboard like `blah~iphone` & `blah~ipad` but it is throwing error like this:

```
2014-01-21 17:05:44.941 test[2709:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/3D8EC72E-D20D-4C60-A413-E8040A455262/blah.app> (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-aYh-JW-qLA' and directory 'blah.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d4edf4b 0x37c846af 0x2d4ede8d 0x2ffbfe39 0x3010c03d 0x40ff5 0x2fcd12ff 0x2fcd0d4f 0x2fccb353 0x2fc6641f 0x2fc65721 0x2fccab3d 0x3211670d 0x321162f7 0x2d4b89df 0x2d4b897b 0x2d4b714f 0x2d421c27 0x2d421a0b 0x2fcc9dd9 0x2fcc5049 0x4134d 0x3818cab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea??

Comment: Seems like there is a typo here `blah.storyboardc` Notice the extra `c` at the end.

Comment: also try changing the same in the plist file

Comment: @Desdenova .. I also thought so, but its not.. that is compiler generated error

Comment: @Bonnie .. that too doesn't work.. kept "blah" for both keys. Tried with all options.

Comment: If you are using storyboards why are you managing the window manually? Why don't you just return `YES` and set the main interface files from the target settings?

Comment: @Desdenova.. For that I would like you to read question once again. Still, if you can help with multiple storyboards using IB, post your solution as answer & i'll be grateful to you.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but I don't understand why you are managing the window manually if you are using storyboard files.

I think you are adding universal support to an already existing project. Because if you create a new universal app everything will be just as you needed.

You need your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in your app delegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

And your target settings should look like this, notice the iPhone / iPad switch and select different storyboards for each device.

[image]

Comment: Yeah exactly.. You are missing a lot many things. What I am asking here for is, how to have same name for both storyboards :(

Comment: Yes thought so.. blah_iPhone, blah_iPad is the best you can do.

Comment: No.. there is some concept with tilde(~) symbol.. just have to work for it.

Comment: I think I've found what you are looking for. Good luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742930/ios-universal-development-use-of-tilde-sign-in-xib-file-name-for-different