# Use different images for different devices/resolutions like how you use the tilde (~) to differentiate between iPhones and iPads?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742930/ios-universal-development-use-of-tilde-sign-in-xib-file-and-image-name-for) explains how to label assets such that you can use the same filename in code (e.g., "Button.png"), and Xcode automagically chooses the right image based on whether the device is an iPhone or iPad.

You just need to use the tilde sign (~).

Is there a similar convention for differentiating between different devices? For instance, we need different images for the 4S and the 7+. Right now, we check the height of the device in code and change the filename accordingly, but this feels hackish.

Comment: You should definitely look at using asset catalogs.  You can even include scalable (PDF, not SVG unfortunately) images

Comment: @Paulw11 yup, definitely! but that still doesn't solve the issue of different image sizes (different sizes, not resolutions) for different devices. for instance, the 4S and the 7 have different width-to-height ratios.

Comment: No, I'm afraid there isn't any magic way of doing that.  Generally it is best to try and build adaptive UI through constraints and autolayout and just scale an image at runtime if required, but if you require pixel-perfect placement then you may just need to keep doing what you are doing.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thanks. could you please post as an answer so you can receive credit?

Answer (score 0):

Closest I came up with was using [DeviceKit](https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit) and creating 2 entries in xcassets. AppLogo has 2x and 3x images. AppLogoSmall has 2x image for the "small screen devices." My app is new so I didn't need to worry about iPhones less than 5.

```
    let titleImage: UIImage?
    //get the device
    let device = Device()

    //list of small screen devices
    let smallScreenDevices: [Device] = [.iPhone5, .iPhone5c, .iPhone5s, .iPhoneSE, .simulator(.iPhone5), .simulator(.iPhone5c), .simulator(.iPhone5s), .simulator(.iPhoneSE)]

    //check if device has small screen
    if device.isOneOf(smallScreenDevices){
        titleImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppLogoSmall")
    }
    else{
        titleImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppLogo")
    }

    let titleImageView = UIImageView.init(image: titleImage)
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    //titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView
```

Comment: don't you still need to support 4S devices?

Comment: No. It's for iOS 10 +